# Taylor s inequality

Tags: taylor-expansion

Apply Taylor´s inequality to derive the quadratic Taylor approximation of $e^x$ at $x=0$.

Could anyone help me out? I tried looking up the definition but I am not sure what is meant by "at $x$ is $0$". Does that mean that the value of a in the Taylor inequality should be $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall make the Taylor approximation at $x=0$ which will be something like 
$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(|x|^3)$$
Because of
$$f(0+h)= f(0) + f'(0)\cdot h +\frac{f''(0)}{2} \cdot h^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(\xi)}{6} h^3$$
So yeah the value of $a$ is 0

Comment: I came this far, however, this does not tell you anything yet about the remainder. Could you help me on how I should use the Taylor inequality to do this?

Comment: well the third derivative of $\exp(x)$ is $\exp(x)$  so absolute values of the reminder is $\leq \frac{|x|^3}{6}\exp(|x|)$.

Comment: If you make 2 cases you get a better one, you will have for $x<0$ $$ |r(x)|< - \frac{x^3}{6}$$

Comment: Why did you fill in exp(x)? Doesnt the Taylor inequality state Rn ≤ M/(n+1)!|x-a|^(n+1)?

Comment: the $\exp(|x|)$ is the $M$ ...

Comment: Note that the error term becomes pretty useless for $x$ large. But for say $x=0.1$, even if we make the very conservative estimate $e^\xi\lt 3$, we find that the error is $\lt \frac{1}{2000}$.